# NetSuite Advanced HTML Extending Footer background to full page size

Tags: html, css, netsuite, footer

I'm working on the NetSuite pdf template, however, according to the requirements obtained, I need to have only the footer background on the full page width. I tried some suggestions found online and on this platform but it just doesn't want to let loose. When I increase the width:150% but it only extends to the right-hand side and the text on the row goes off-center.

```css
  .footer-container {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
table.footer {
  background-color: #484848;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
table.footer td {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer-container">
  <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" class="footer">
    <tr>
      <td align="center">www.XZY.com</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

This is the html preview:

[image: this is the html preview]

and here is what it should look like:

[image: and here is what it should look like]

Comment: If you are creating a pdf some of what you are seeing will have to do with your page setup. You are not going to get a full bleed output when your printed page has margins.